# Linq + MoreLinq how to aggregate one result prop to list?

Tags: c#, linq, morelinq

I have a problem with query, please take a look.
My aim is:

- I need to take all `Products` with one `Image`.
- `Products` has `Values` which are some additional information aboute the product like specification etc.
- `Image` and `Values` can be `null`
- Wanna return all `Products` with `Image` and `Values`
- For `Values` I need only `Ids` so its ok to get `List<int> of Values`
- `ProductValues` and `ImageObjects` are connecting table for relationship --> `Products` can have many `ProductValues` also `Products` can have many `ImageObjects` but can have one `Image`
- `DistinctBy` is from `more linq`

**Question** I don't know how to aggregate `Values` in correct way to return list of `Values` per `Product`

**PS** I'm also using more linq

```
var q1 = (from p in Products
        join pv in ProductValues on p.ProductId equals pv.ProductId into ljpv
        from pv in ljpv.DefaultIfEmpty()
        select new
            {
                ProductId = p.ProductId,
                Description = p.Description,
                Name = p.Name,
                Price = p.Price,
                Quantity = p.Quantity,
                Type = p.Type,
                Values = (from v in ValueTypes 
                            where v.ValueId == pv.ValueId 
                            select new {
                             ValueId = v.ValueId
                            }).ToList(),
                ImageObjects = (from io in ImageObjects
                                where io.ProductId == p.ProductId && io.IsDefault == true
                                select new 
                                    {
                                               Image = io.Image,
                                               IsDefault = io.IsDefault,
                                               ProductId = io.ProductId
                                    })
                                .ToList()
            })
        .DistinctBy(x=>x.Name)
        .OrderBy(x=>x.Name);
q1.Dump();
```

**Answer**
`Values = (from tmp in ljpv select new { ValueId = tmp.ValueId}),`

I know that this is not place to answer, but meaby someone will have any addvices to my code or meaby it can be done more clear or faster.
I've been wondering how to do this query for a long time, but as I wrote to you, I got a dazzle:)

---

after `@Harald Coppoolse` answer - the code is more faster!

```
                return context.Product.GroupJoin(
                    context.ProductValue,
                    context.ImageObject.Include(x => x.Image),
                    p => p.ProductId,
                    pv => pv.ProductId,
                    io => io.ProductId,
                    (p, pv, io) => new ProductModel
                    {
                        ProductId = p.ProductId,
                        Name = p.Name,
                        Price = p.Price,
                        ProductValue = pv
                            .Select(npv => new ProductValueModel
                            {
                                ProductId = npv.ProductId,
                            }).ToList(),
                        ImageObject = io
                            .Select(nio => new ImageObjectModel
                            {
                                Image = nio.Image.DtoToModel(),
                                IsDefault = nio.IsDefault,
                                ProductId = nio.ProductId
                            }).ToList(),
                    });
```

Comment: "Products can have many ImageObjects but can have one Image" - what does that mean?

Comment: @NetMage - "Products can have many ImageObjects but can have one Image" - what does that mean? 

"Products can have many ImageObjects" - `ImageObjects` this is relationship table beetween `Products`, many others tables and `Images`

`Products` or something else --> `ImageObjects` --> `Image`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you have a table of `Products` and a table of `ProductValues` with a one-to-many relation: every `Product` has zero or more `ProductValues` and every `ProductValue` belongs to exactly one `Product`, namely the `Product` that the foreign key `ProductId` points to.

You want (several properties of) all `Products`, each `Product` with its `ProductValues`. After that you `DistinctBy` and `OrderBy`, but that is not your problem.

Whenever you want "items with their sub-items", like "Schools with their Students", "Customers with their Orders", "Orders with their Order lines", consider using [Enumerable.GroupJoin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupjoin?view=netframework-4.8)

GroupJoin is in fact a Left Outer Join, followed by a GroupBy.

```
var productsWithTheirProductValues = products.GroupJoin(  // GroupJoin Products
    productValues,                                        // with ProductValues
    product => product.ProductId,           // from every Product take the ProductId
    productValue => productValue.ProductId, // from every ProductValue take the foreign key

    // ResultSelector: take the product with its zero or more matching ProductValues
    // to make a new object:
    (product, productValuesOfThisProduct) => new
    {
        // Select only the product properties you plan to use:
        Id = product.Id,
        Name = product.Name,
        Price = product.Price,
        ...

        ProductValues = productValuesOfThisProduct
            // only if you don't want all ProductValues of this product:
            .Where(productValue => ...)   

            .Select(productValue => new
            {
                // again select only the properties you plan to use
                Id = productValue.Id,
                ...

                // not needed: the foreign key, you already know the value
                // ProductId = productValue.ProductId,
            })
            .ToList(),
    });
```

In your case, you don't want to GroupJoin two sequences, but three sequences. You'l need to do an extra GroupJoin:

```
var result = products.GroupJoin(productValues,
    product => product.ProductId,
    productValue => productValue.ProductId,

    // ResultSelector: remember the product and all its productValues
    (product, productValuesOfThisProduct) => new
    {
        Product = product,
        ProductValues = productValuesOfThisProduct,
    })

    // now do the 2nd join:
    .GroupJoin(imageObjects,
        firstJoinResult => firstJoinResult.Product.ProductId,
        imageObject => imageObject.ProductId,

        // result selector:
        (firstJoinResult, imageObjectsOfThisProduct) => new
        {
            Product = firstJoinResult.Product,
            ProductValues = firstJoinResult.ProductValues,
            ImageObjects = imageObjectsOfThisProduct,
        })

        // take each element of this group join result and select the items that you want
        .Select(joinResult => new
        {
            ProductId = joinResult.Product.ProductId,
            Price = joinResult.Product.Price,
            ...

            ProductValues = joinResult.ProductValues.Select(productValue => new
            {
                 ...
            })
            .ToList(),

            ImageObjects = joinResult.ImageObjects.Select(imageObject => new
            {
                ...
            })
            .ToList(),
       });
```

This looks horrible. So if you have to do a GroupJoin with three tables more often, consider to create a GroupJoin for three tables:

```
static IEnumerable<TResult> GroupJoin<T1, T2, T3, TKey, TResult>(
   this IEnumerable<T1> source1, IEnumerable<T2> source2, IEnumerable<T3> source3,
   Func<T1, TKey> key1Selector,
   Func<T2, TKey> key2Selector,
   Func<T3, TKey> key3Selector,
   Func<T1, IEnumerable<T2>, IEnumerable<T3>, TResult> resultSelector)
{
     // put all source2 and source3 elements in lookuptables, using the keyselector
     var lookup2 = source2.ToLookup(item => key2Selector(item));
     var lookup3 = source3.ToLookup(item => key3Selector(item));

     // now for every source1 item, get all source2 and source3 items with the same key
     // and create the result:
     foreach (var item1 in source1)
     {
         TKey key1 = key1Selector(item1);
         IEnumerable<T2> items2 = lookup2[key1];
         IEnumerable<T3> items3 = lookup3[key1];
         // returns empty collection if no items with this key

         TResult result = resultSelector(item1, items2, items3);
         yield return result;
    }
}
```

usage:

```
var result = products.GroupJoin(productValues, imageObjects,
   product => product.ProductId,
   productValue => productValue.ProductId,
   imageObject => imageObject.ProductId,

   (product, productValues, imageObjects) => new
   {
       ProductId = product.ProductId,
       ...

       ProductValues = productValues.Select(productValue => new
       {
          ...
       }),
       ImageObjects = imageObjects.Select(imageObject => new
       {
          ...
       }),
    });
```

Comment: for double sure at `Extension`: there is `var lookup3 = source2.ToLookup(item => key3Selector(item));` it should be `var lookup3 = source3. (...)`
and
there is `IEnumerable<T3> items3 = lookup3[key];` it should be `(...) items3 = lookup3[key];`?

Comment: Apparently you undestood my answer! You don't need my knowledge anymore ;)